How do you get the Solana platform tools version? Or the `rustc` version used by Solana to compile programs?
When building a Solana rust program, it does NOT use your normal system's rust compiler (rustc), instead cargo build-sbf uses the Solana "platform tools" under the hood which ships a separate version of rustc which is used to actually compile Solana programs.

How can you find the version of the platform tools your system will use?
How can you find the rustc version your program will be compiled with?

My current Solana/Agave CLI version is:
solana --version
# output: solana-cli 2.0.0 (src:16de8b75; feat:4288794394, client:Agave)

And my current system's rustc version:
rustc --version
# output: rustc 1.78.0 (9b00956e5 2024-04-29)


How to get your platform tools and rustc version for Solana builds
To find the platform tools version AND the rustc version that will be used to compile your Solana programs, run the following command:
cargo build-sbf --version

Example output:
solana-cargo-build-sbf 2.0.0
platform-tools v1.41
rustc 1.75.0

Build Solana program with a specific platform tools version
If you need to, you can run a build using a specific platform tools version for your build:
cargo build-sbf --tools-version v1.43

